# How can I login to icloud.com from my iPhone?

Tags: ios, icloud, reminders

I was reading the following answer which tells you how to enable shared Reminder lists:

[Is it possible to share reminders?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28246/is-it-possible-to-share-reminders/28256#28256)

However, at the moment, the only way I can get to icloud.com is from my iPhone (site is blocked at my work).

When you go to icloud.com from your iPhone it doesn't let you login and see the actual site features, it only links to information on how to setup iCloud (and Find my iPhone / Find my friends)

Any ideas how to get full icloud.com functionality from the iPhone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, nor was it possible with Mobile Me.  Particularly irritating when a number of people share an iPad and don't want to enable full email for each other for example.  I'm afraid there is no way around it, unless perhaps you can download a different browser from the App Store that will enable you to change your user agent string to trick the website into thinking you are using Firefox or something that isn't mobile safari.

Comment: Actually with Mobile Me it was possible to use it via a web browser integrated in another app. Tried it with iCloud and Evernote today and unfortunately it doesn't work that way any longer.

Comment: @patrix That is interesting - seems like it theoretically could still be possible then if there is some app out there that makes icloud.com think it is not an iOS device...

Comment: The "Atomic" browser available inthe App Store can spoof the user agent string, but only in the paid version.  However, the Lite (free) version whilst not offering the choice of user agent, does seem to use something other than Mobile Safari, as it complains the browser is not compatible when trying to log into me.com, and it sort of half loads the login page rather than the setup page, but fails to complete.  Pointing it at iCloud.com produces the normal setup page though, so perhaps they are detecting your remote device better these days to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

The  Way To Access iCloud Info is through your phone apps.  Contacts for your adressbook in groups iCloud Will be an automatically created one.  Same with calendars, pages, numbers , etc.  So basically you need to take your wallet out to buy Apple's apps..  I heard that  iWork (which contains pages, numbers and keynote presentations) eventually will become a paid service...

Works well though, for phone apps.

Not all functions are available though has on desktop.

And like mentioned above, browsers where you can choose how the present yourself to the server.  Internet Explorer, Safari, Firefox, etc.

Comment: Do you have any prove which can confirm your thought about iCloud becoming a paid service?