# How can I share reminders from one iphone to another?

Tags: icloud, sharing, reminders

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to share reminders?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28246/is-it-possible-to-share-reminders)

We have 2 iphones between us, both running iOS 5.  Is there a way to share reminders between them?  They have different apple IDs associated with them.  It looks like this was possible via iCloud, but I cannot find that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Pick one of your apple ID's and log in on both phones with this ID. In settings under iCloud you can select what you want to sync, just turn off the features you do not wish to share.

More info on using multiple accounts:
http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4020?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US